# Back flap of an envelope

Tags: meaning, verbs

I am wiring a letter for a company and it said it should be signed at the back flap.
Can anyone tell me what the back flap of an envelope is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see an image [here](http://0.tqn.com/d/desktoppub/1/0/y/l/envelopeflaps.gif).

Essentially it's the only movable part of the envelope, creating the seal between the front and back ends by covering the open portion. Signing the back is used as a (shoddy) security measure to ensure the letter hasn't been tampered with.

The actual "flap" will depend on the type of envelope, but they are referring to whatever part forces the seal of the envelope. [Here's](http://gradschool.about.com/od/askingforletters/f/letenvelope.htm) the practice of signing envelopes containing letters of recommendation explained.

Comment: is that done in the US? I never heard of it. Does one sign across the tip (writing on both the flap and the back)?

Comment: @Susan Eh, when I was applying to universities I know Oxford asked for this to be done with my letters of recommendation. But yes, it may be a primarily American thing. I've updated my answer with a description of this practice. Since most communication is now digital, the practice may be falling out of fashion entirely. But yes, you sign on the actual seal so that half of your signature is on the flap and half is on the portion being sealed. (The logic is that if the letter was opened, the signature would be broken. I'll try to find an image of what I mean.

Comment: @Susan It's akin to the wax seals used in history for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally referred to as a *[top flap](http://desktoppub.about.com/od/envelopes/ss/envelope_parts.htm)* or a *[seal flap](http://www.pdmny.com/envsize.html)*.

[image]